# PNG bullet points alignment

Tags: html, css, png, html-lists

I have managed to display graphical bullet points on my website but I cant get the point to align to the middle of the text properly.

It's as if I just need to add margin to the bullet image that doesn't effect the text.

Here's the page I'm working on: http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/youth-community/our-work/adult-homelessness/

It's just a standard ul with li elements:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS I have:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:40px 0 40px 0;
}

li { 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 2.3em;
  text-indent: -2.3em;
}

li:before {
  /* -content: "●";-*/
  content:"";
  background-image: url('http://new.leicesterymca.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/arrow-bullet.png');
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: .7em;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2f9395;
}

a:hover {
  color: #163a52;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding...

```
li:before {
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

to your CSS

Answer (score 1):

This will works for you

```
    li:before {
     vertical-align: middle
    }
```